# Consolidate 2 queries with similar where clauses but different aggregate function targets

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I have 2 queries that work fine separately.  Given they are similar, I'd like to consolidate them into one performant query.  Seems straightforward as the where clauses are similar.  But the sum, count, and min functions all apply to different rows and get in the way.

Context:

- Users can score (or rate) a location and get points
- User A can refer User B and get referral points when User B first submits a score
- Points expire after a certain date
- Goal is to build a leaderboard of users and their total points for scoring and referring for a particular location (area/country)
- Positional parameters are filled in with hard values for 'Massachusetts', 'United States', and the scoreDateTime expiration date and are unfortunately duplicated in both select subqueries.

Question:

How can the query below be reorganized to combine constraints?  There must be a way to start with a list of scores from a specific location after a certain date.  The only complication is to get User B's first score date and only offer referral points to User A if it is after the expiration date.

```
select scoring.userId, scoring.points + referring.points as leaderPoints
from (
    select   userId, sum(ratingPoints) as points
    from     scores s, locations l
    where    s.locationId = l.locationId and
             l.locationArea = 'Massachusetts' and
             l.locationCountry = 'United States' and
             s.scoreDateTime > '2016-04-16 18:50:53.154' and
             s.userId != 0
    group by s.userId
) as scoring

join (
    select u1.userId, count(*) * 20 as points
    from users u0
    join users u1 on u0.userId = u1.userId
    join users u2 on u2.referredByEmail = u1.emailAddress
    join scores s on u2.userId = s.userId
    join locations l on s.locationId = l.locationId
    where    l.locationArea = 'Massachusetts' and
             l.locationCountry = 'United States' and
             scoreDateTime = (
                 select min(scoreDateTime)
                 from   scores
                 where  userId = u2.userId
             ) and
             scoreDateTime >= '2016-04-16 18:50:53.154'
    group by u1.userId
) as referring on scoring.userId = referring.userId
order by leaderPoints desc
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Stan Shaw but I was unable to get your query to work on MySQL to test the results.  However, I did notice a special case that was not covered by my original query.  A user can get refer points from areas in which they themselves have not submitted scores.  As long as the new user scores in that area, they get refer points there.

Here is the final query I'm using.  I was not able to consolidate the duplicate where clauses in a way that appeared performant.

```
select userId, sum(points) as leaderPoints
from (

    select   s.userId, sum(s.ratingPoints) as points
    from     scores s, locations l
    where    s.locationId = l.locationId and  
             l.locationArea = 'Georgia' and  
             l.locationCountry = 'United States' and  
             s.scoreDateTime >= '2016-04-05 03:00:00.000' and  
             s.userId != 1
    group by userId

    union

    select   u1.userId, 20 as points
    from     users u0, users u1, users u2, scores s, locations l
    where    u0.userId = u1.userId and
             u2.referredByEmail = u1.emailAddress and
             u2.userId = s.userId and
             s.locationId = l.locationId and
             l.locationArea = 'Georgia' and  
             l.locationCountry = 'United States' and  
             scoreDateTime >= '2016-04-05 03:00:00.000' and
             scoreDateTime = (
                 select min(scoreDateTime) 
                 from   scores  
                 where  userId = u2.userId  
             )

) as pointsEarned
group by userId
order by leaderPoints desc
limit 10
order by leaderPoints desc  
limit 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but it should do the trick.  The Cross Apply is for readability...it'll hurt performance, but this doesn't seem to be a particularly process-intensive query, so I would keep it.

Please give it a try and let me know if you have any questions.

```
SELECT  U.UserID, 
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN S.UserID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE S.ratingPoints END), 0) AS [Rating Points], 
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN SS.userID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 20 END), 0) AS [Referral Points]
FROM Users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores S
    ON S.userID = U.userID
    AND S.scoreDateTime >= '2016-04-16 18:50:53.154'
LEFT OUTER JOIN locations L
    ON S.locationID = L.locationID
    AND L.locationArea = 'Massachusetts'
    AND L.LocationCountry = 'United States'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users U2
    ON U2.referredByEmail = U.emailAddress
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores SS
    ON SS.userID = U2.userID
LEFT OUTER JOIN locations LL
    ON SS.locationID = LL.locationID
    AND LL.locationArea = 'Massachusetts'
    AND LL.locationCountry = 'United States'
    AND SS.scoreDateTime >= '2016-04-16 18:50:53.154'
    AND SS.scoreDateTime = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(scoreDateTime)
            FROM scores
            where userID = U2.userID
        )
GROUP BY U.userID
```

EDIT:

Modified answer to remove Cross Apply

Comment: I'm using MySQL, where apparently CROSS APPLY does not seem to apply.  I was hoping to consolidate the locationArea, locationCountry, and scoreDateTime constraints as they are duplicated.  The only time I reach outside that list of scores is the min(scoreDateTime) to get the referred user's first score datetime.  I only want to award referral bonus points if that date is after the cutoff date.

Comment: @jmelvin I've modified the answer to remove Cross Apply.